# Volley request takes to much time

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley

I had implemented the volley request before and it was working perfectly, with some changes i did it stoped working like i want ( i will explain the changes after code).

So basicly i want to request to volley passing 4 parameters (the method, the url, the token and the data)

**so i do something like this:**

IResult mResultCallback2 = null;

```
public void sendFotoServer(){
        String url = connectionTxt + "/fotos/" + specieId + "/plants";

        HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

        byte[] capture = encodeImage(b);
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(capture,1);
        Log.d("encodedImage",encodedImage);

        params.put("base64", encodedImage);
        params.put("lat",String.valueOf(photo.getLat()));
        params.put("lon",String.valueOf(photo.getLon()));
        params.put("alt",String.valueOf(photo.getAlt()));
        params.put("date",photo.getTime());

        JSONObject sendObj = new JSONObject(params);

        PostPhotoVolleyCallback();

        mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallback2, this);

        mVolleyService.postDataVolley("POSTCALL", url, sendObj,token);
    }

 void PostPhotoVolleyCallback(){
    mResultCallback2 = new IResult() {
        @Override
        public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("HELLO","HELLOTHERE");
            Log.d("resposta2",response.toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(SimiliarPhotos.this,PlantFeed.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONArray response) {
            Log.d("HELLO",response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error) {
           Log.d("errorV",error.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
    };
}
```

**i have defined a interface so i can reuse the calls to volley like this:**

```
package com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.services;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.interfaces.IResult;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by FilipeCosta on 19/05/2017.
 */

public class VolleyService {
    IResult mResultCallback = null;
    Context mContext;

    public VolleyService(IResult resultCallback, Context context){
        mResultCallback = resultCallback;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void postDataVolleyAuth(final String requestType,String url,JSONObject sendObj){
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObj = new JsonObjectRequest(url,sendObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if(mResultCallback != null) {
                        mResultCallback.notifySuccess(requestType, response);
                    }
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (mResultCallback != null) {
                        mResultCallback.notifyError(requestType, error);
                    }
                }
            });

            jsonObj.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            queue.add(jsonObj);

        }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }




    public void postDataVolley(final String requestType,String url,JSONObject sendObj,final String token){
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObj = new JsonObjectRequest(url,sendObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if(mResultCallback != null) {
                        mResultCallback.notifySuccess(requestType, response);
                    }
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if(mResultCallback != null) {
                        mResultCallback.notifyError(requestType,error);
                    }
                }
            }) {

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    Log.d("tokenXX", token);
                    headers.put("x-access-token", token);
                    return headers;
                }
            };

            jsonObj.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            queue.add(jsonObj);

        }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }

    public void getDataVolley(final String requestType, String url, final String token){
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

            JsonArrayRequest jsonArray = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    if(mResultCallback != null)
                        mResultCallback.notifySuccess(requestType, response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders(){
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    Log.d("tokenXX",token);
                    headers.put("x-access-token", token);
                    return headers;
                }
            };

            jsonArray.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            queue.add(jsonArray);

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }



    public void getDataObjectVolley(final String requestType, String url, final String token){
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if(mResultCallback != null)
                        mResultCallback.notifySuccess(requestType, response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders(){
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    Log.d("tokenXX",token);
                    headers.put("x-access-token", token);
                    return headers;
                }
            };

            jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }


    public void putDataVolley(final String requestType, String url, final String token){
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObj = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT,url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if(mResultCallback != null) {
                        mResultCallback.notifySuccess(requestType, response);
                    }
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if(mResultCallback != null) {
                        mResultCallback.notifyError(requestType,error);
                    }
                }
            }){

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders(){
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    Log.d("tokenXX",token);
                    headers.put("x-access-token", token);
                    return headers;
                }
            };

            jsonObj.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            queue.add(jsonObj);

        }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }


}
```

the problem is that i get a response but just like 5 minutes later, something like this:

```
POST /fotos/10/plants - - ms - -
POST /fotos/10/plants - - ms - -
POST /fotos/10/plants - - ms - -
POST /fotos/10/plants - - ms - -
POST /fotos/10/plants - - ms - -
POST /fotos/10/plants - - ms - -
POST /fotos/10/plants - - ms - -
POST /fotos/10/plants - - ms - -
POST /fotos/10/plants - - ms - -
```

the only thing that i changed was the way i get the data on this activity, at begin my model was a serializable, i changed it to parcelable, i pass my image trough a file and convert it to byte[] and after base64, i tried to debug and all my data was present, any tip here?

Thanks :)